# I'm designing a car design program and trying to follow a set of restrictions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to follow these restrictions: 1) You may only print string literals and values obtained from your car object, 2) , you may only have a single Car& parameter, and 3) you may not call the setSpeed() member.

So far, no success. I was hoping you'd guys walk me through it.

I currently only have two errors, but there was so much that was shown to me when the errors came up, I believe I can possibly only give you an idea by showing a screenshot.

http://prntscr.com/c2e8av

This is my main program.

```
    //Car design
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Car header.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    //function prototypes
    void findSpeedGoingUp (int &speed, int yearModel, string make);
    void findSpeedGoingDown(int &speed, int yearModel, string make);


    using namespace std;

    //global constants
    const int NUM_FOR_INCREASE=80;
    const int NUM_FOR_CAL=5;
    const int ONE_FOR_CAL=1;
    int main()
    {
        //some variables
        int yearModel;
        string make;
        int speed=0;


        //calling the functions
        findSpeedGoingUp(speed, yearModel, make);
        findSpeedGoingDown(speed, yearModel, make);


        system("Pause");
        return 0;
    }//end main

    //function for increasing speed
    void findSpeedGoingUp(int &speed, int yearModel, string make)
    {
        Car carObject(yearModel, make);



            //user input
        cout << "Enter the car model year" << endl;
        cin >> carObject.setYearModel(yearModel);
        cout << "Enter the cars make" << endl;
        cin >> carObject.setMake(make);
        cout << "The model year is " << carObject.getYearModel()<< endl;
        cout << "The make is " << carObject.getMake() << endl;
        cout << "The speed is " << carObject.getSpeed()<< endl;
        cout << "Let's see what it can do." << endl;
        cout << "The speed is,..." << endl;

        for(int n=50; n<NUM_FOR_INCREASE; ++n)
        {
            carObject.accelerate();

            speed=speed+NUM_FOR_CAL;
            cout << carObject.getSpeed() << " ";
        }//end for loop
        cout << "\nStop! Stop! Let me out." << endl;
    }//end findSpeedGoingUp

    //function for decreasing speed
    void findSpeedGoingDown(int &speed, int yearModel, string make)
    {
        Car carObject(yearModel, make);

        for(int n = 50; n < NUM_FOR_INCREASE + ONE_FOR_CAL; ++n)
        {
            carObject.brake();

            cout << carObject.getSpeed() << " ";

            speed = speed - NUM_FOR_CAL;
        }//end for loop
        cout << "\nI'll walk from here." << endl;
    }//end findSpeedGoingDown
```

This is my class (or car header),

```
//Car design header
#ifndef CAR_HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define CAR_HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Car
{
private:
    //private fields to hold data
    int yearModel;
    string make;
    int speed;

    //constructor
public:

    //constructor
    Car(int ym, string mk)
    {
        yearModel=ym;
        make=mk;
        speed=0;
    }//end Car

    void setYearModel(int aYearModel)
    {
        yearModel=aYearModel;

    }//end setYearModel


    int getYearModel()
    {
        return yearModel;
    }//end returnYearModel

    void setMake(string aMake)
    {
        make=aMake;
    }//end setMake

    string getMake()
    {
        return make;
    }//end returnMake

    void setSpeed(int aSpeed)
    {
        speed=aSpeed;
    }//end setSpeed

    int getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }//end returnSpeed

    //methods to use in main program

    void accelerate()
    {
        speed += 5;
    }// accelerate

    void brake()
    {
        speed -= 5;
    }//end brake
};//end Car
#endif // CAR_HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: What are the specific errors you're getting?

Comment: It was only letting me show you one link. Haha. These are the two errors.

http://prntscr.com/c2eazo
http://prntscr.com/c2eb49

@SebastianLenartowicz

Comment: You can (and should) copy/paste the text of the errors into your question.  They are much more readable than pictures and won't disappear if those links expire.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `cin >> afunction()`

```
cin >> carObject.setYearModel(yearModel);
```

You have to define a temp variable

```
int ym;
cin >> ym;
cin >> carObject.setYearModel(ym);
```

There are so much errors in your code that I had to change a lot of things to get the expected output:

```
Enter the car model year
1970
Enter the cars make
renault
The model year is 1970
The make is renault
The speed is 0
Let's see what it can do.

The speed is,...
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190 200 210 220 230 240 250 260 270 2
80 290 300
Stop! Stop! Let me out.
295 285 275 265 255 245 235 225 215 205 195 185 175 165 155 145 135 125 115 105 95 85 75 65 55 45 35
 25 15 5 -5
I'll walk from here.
```

`Car.cpp` now contains this (bad design, the main should be somewhere else, okay!):

```
//Car design
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_FOR_INCREASE=80;
const int NUM_FOR_CAL=5;
const int ONE_FOR_CAL=1;


//function for increasing speed
void Car::findSpeedGoingUp()
{  

   cout << "The model year is " << getYearModel()<< endl;
    cout << "The make is " << getMake() << endl;
    cout << "The speed is " << getSpeed()<< endl;
    cout << "Let's see what it can do." << endl;
    cout << "The speed is,..." << endl;

    for(int n=50; n<NUM_FOR_INCREASE; ++n)
    {
        accelerate();

        speed+=NUM_FOR_CAL;
        cout << getSpeed() << " ";
    }//end for loop
    cout << "\nStop! Stop! Let me out." << endl;
}//end findSpeedGoingUp

//function for decreasing speed
void Car::findSpeedGoingDown()
{


    for(int n = 50; n < NUM_FOR_INCREASE + ONE_FOR_CAL; ++n)
    {
        brake();

        cout << getSpeed() << " ";

        speed = speed - NUM_FOR_CAL;
    }//end for loop
    cout << "\nI'll walk from here." << endl;
}//end findSpeedGoingDown

//global constants
int main()
{
    int yearModel;
    string make;

    //some variables
      //user input
    cout << "Enter the car model year" << endl;
    cin >> yearModel;
    cout << "Enter the cars make" << endl;
    cin >> make;
    Car carObject(yearModel, make);        


    //calling the functions
    carObject.findSpeedGoingUp();
    carObject.findSpeedGoingDown();


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}//end main
```

`Car.h` (yes, I have renamed your file since putting spaces in file names is ill-advised)
Note that I have added your speed increase/decrease methods as member methods, and I declare the only instance in the main. Makes a lot more sense like that.

Please meditate this :)

```
//Car design header
#ifndef CAR_HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define CAR_HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Car
{
private:
    //private fields to hold data
    int yearModel;
    string make;
    int speed;

    //constructor
public:

    //constructor
    Car(int ym, string mk)
    {
        yearModel=ym;
        make=mk;
        speed=0;
    }//end Car

    void setYearModel(int aYearModel)
    {
        yearModel=aYearModel;

    }//end setYearModel


    int getYearModel()
    {
        return yearModel;
    }//end returnYearModel

    void setMake(string aMake)
    {
        make=aMake;
    }//end setMake

    string getMake()
    {
        return make;
    }//end returnMake

    void setSpeed(int aSpeed)
    {
        speed=aSpeed;
    }//end setSpeed

    int getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }//end returnSpeed

    //methods to use in main program

    void accelerate()
    {
        speed += 5;
    }// accelerate

    void brake()
    {
        speed -= 5;
    }//end brake
    void findSpeedGoingUp();
    void findSpeedGoingDown();

};//end Car
#endif // CAR_HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

#### in a nutshell what did I fix in your code ?

- created the sole instance of `Car` in the `main`, after prompting user for make and year.
- moved the speed change methods to the object itself, makes more sense!
- that allowed me to directly call the `getSpeed()` et al methods without an instance name, on the object itself
- that allowed me to increase and then decrease speed with coherent results (you instanciated 2 different objects hence the negative values you got)

#### what I did not fix in your code (most suitable for code review) ?

- passing `string` as in parameter makes a copy, and it's bad for performance, prefer passing `const string &` to pass by constant reference

  `void setMake(const string &aMake)
   {
       make=aMake;
   }`
- getter methods should have `const` attribute to be able to be called on constant references

  `const string &getMake() const { return make; }
   int getYearModel() const
   {
       return yearModel;
   }`

Comment: Fabre

Why can't I use yearModel and the other variables in main for this?

Comment: TW you're constructing the object and set the properties interactively later. What's the use??

I don't understand what you're saying. Classes were taught very poorly in my class, so bare with me. 

@Jean-Francois Fabre

Comment: I'm getting a weird output 
http://prntscr.com/c2eih4

@Jean-Francois Fabre

Comment: you don't seem to get the object concept. Let me edit my post again.